# jQuery slideshow Load images from <li>

Tags: image, tags, slideshow

My name is Linda and i am new to this board :).

I am working on the supersized slideshow at the moment and what I'm trying to achieve is taking an automatically generated list like this:

Edit:

Thanks for your fast answer, but i think you misunderstood this part :): e.g. i try to get this:

```
<ul>
<li><span class="image">/images/image1.jpg</span></li>
<li><span class="image">/images/image2.jpg</span></li>
</ul>
```

**with js to this:**

```
slides : [
            {'image1' : "/images/image1.jpg"},
            {'image3' : "/images/image3.jpg"} ],
```

I nearly works with this http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/bYs4x/ script but the code above inserts some exclamation marks around *image*. How can i get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

well Im not sure exactly how to fix this but I think you will have to do this

```
     slides : [
            {'image1' : "/images/image1.jpg"},
            {'image2' : "/images/image2.jpg"},
            {'image3' : "/images/image3.jpg"} ],
```

And I think you will have to reference the JSON elements as such,

slides[0].image1, slides[0].image2....